# i want to update a database field on page load

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to update a column in a table during session log out. I have a functional logout script, I would just like to update a 'voted' to a value of '1' while logging out.

```php
 <?php   
 //logout.php
    session_start();
    [code here to say]
        UPDATE registrants  SET voted='1' WHERE id=:id
    session_destroy();  
        header("location:thanks.php");  
 ?>
```

Comment: "on page load" or "while logging out." pick one? also make some kind of effort,

Comment: This is only my second time working with php. I’ve spend 4 hours collectively trying to get this column to update during logout. Weather it’s when the login pages loads before destroying the session or anything I can think of around that. To me “on page load” and “while logging out” is the same thing since this bit of code is all that’s contained on the logout page.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your query with an if statement.

Eg
If (!isset($_session['your session']). Then mysqli_query().

Answer (score 0):

```
when user logout,if you want to release user's all session resource:

（1）session_unset();
（2）session_destroy();
if Only use session_destroy(), then  $_SESSION['user_stuff'] still there.
so

    if(isset($_SESSION['user_stuff'])){

        //UPDATE registrants  SET   voted='1' WHERE id=:id;
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();  

    }
```